# Cambiar el tipo de fuente en XtraReport del DevExpress

Tags: vb.net, devexpress

¿Cómo puedo cambiar el tipo de fuente en un registro específico ya sea el tamaño o el estilo de la fuente?

Ejemplo:

```
  1101 Caja y Banco     10,000.00 esto lo quiero en negrita
110101                   5,000.00
110102                   5,000.00 estos dos últimos en letras normales
```

Comment: En las propiedades del label de Caja y Banco intentaste cambiarle la fuente?

Answer (score 0):

Si el tamaño de la fuente depende del valor del registro, utiliza el evento [BeforePrint](https://documentation.devexpress.com/XtraReports/DevExpress.XtraReports.UI.XRControl.BeforePrint.event):

Una ídea sería más o menos así:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using DevExpress.XtraReports.UI;
// ...

private void Control_BeforePrint(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintEventArgs e) {
    decimal valor = GetCurrentColumnValue<decimal>("valor");
    Font fuente = null;
    switch(valor) {
        case 1:
        //fuente 1
        break;
        case 2:
        //fuente 2
        break;
        //etc.
    }
    XRControl control = (XRControl) sender;
    control.Font = fuente;
}
```